# Override the browser default font - but not the code font - in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Let's say, I have a simple, unstyled HTML document - something like this:

```html
<h2>Hello world</h2>

<p><b>This</b> is <i>my</i> code example: <code>code_example.is_here("!")</code>
```

On Firefox, this renders as:

[image: firefox_default_render]

So, Firefox chose some serif font (Firefox Inspector tells me it is "DejaVu Serif") to be the default text font - but chose a different font, a typewriter/monospaced font, for formatting `<code>` (Firefox Inspector tells me it is "DejaVu Sans Mono").

Now, what I want to do, is to override the default text font with a different font, throughout the page, as in here:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Comfortaa";
  /* src: url("../path/to/comfortaa.ttf") format("truetype"); // not using src here, as we load via fonts.googleapis.com for SO code snippet */
}

html *
{
  font-family: Comfortaa !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
<h2>Hello world</h2>

<p><b>This</b> is <i>my</i> code example: <code>code_example.is_here("!")</code>
```

... which renders like this in Firefox:

[image: firefox_render_font]

... however, as you can see, that override also overrode the font for `<code>`.

So, what I want to do is, to override just the default text (the serif font, originally) - but leave the font used in `<code>` as is.

How can I do this with CSS?

EDIT: the way I formulated this, the solution could have been just to override the `<p>` element; but assume in general there may be "wild" text directly in the HTML `<body>` tag. Also `<code>` could appear as child of `<p>`, but it could be also a direct child of `<body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not()` to exclude the `code` element (and `pre`, as asked in the comment below)

You could also exclude more than one specific tag name by just chaining the `:not()` pseudoclass

```css
html *:not(code):not(pre) {
  font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<p>This font is in Arial</p>

<code>Code is not in Arial</code>

<pre>Pre is not in Arial</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioCalderan - I know this was not in the question, but would this also work for `<pre>`?